# z-index layering woes

Tags: css, z-index

I am terrible at css, please bear with me.

Three elements: `.subscribe`, `#pictures`, `#menu`.

These three need both `.subscribe` and `#menu` to be overlay on top of pictures. The css is below (all selectors are correct). I thought just `z-index` and positioning would do it, however, it's not working out.

Anything obviously wrong? Thank you.

```
#slideshow * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  padding: 14px 0 15px;
  width: 926px;
  height: 335px; 
}
#slideshow #pictures { 
  background: url('images/bg.jpg');
  width: 926px;
  height: 335px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#slideshow #pictures li {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 926px;
  z-index: -1;
}
#slideshow #pictures li img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}
#slideshow #menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: 290px;
  padding-right: 20px
  position:relative;
}
#slideshow #menu li {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  z-index: 3;
}
#slideshow #menu li a {
  display: block;
  font: 11px "Lucida Grande", "Verdana";
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 0 7px 28px;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #ccc;
  line-height: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#slideshow #menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#slideshow #menu li.current a {
  font: 15px "Georgia";
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 28px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
#slideshow #pictures .subscribe {
  height: 91px;
  width: 252px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  float: left;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: url('images/SubscribeButton.png');
}
#slideshow #pictures .subscribe:hover {
  background: url('images/SubscribeButton-Dark.png');
}
```

Mark-up:

```
<div id="slideshow">    
      <ul id="pictures">
        <li style="visibility: hidden; zoom: 1; opacity: 0; "> <a class="subscribe"></a><img src="style/images/sample1.jpeg" alt="Slide 1" title="Sample 1" style="display: none; width:926px; height:335px "></li>
        <li style="visibility: hidden; zoom: 1; opacity: 0; "><a class="subscribe"></a><img src="style/images/sample2.jpeg" alt="Buenos Aires" title="Buenos Aires" style="display: none; width:926px; height:335px "></li>
        <li style="visibility: hidden; zoom: 1; opacity: 0; "><a class="subscribe"></a><img src="style/images/Slideshow-Image1.jpg" alt="Our design team creates the perfect collections of white shirts each season" title="Creation" style="display: none; width:926px; height:335px "></li>

      </ul>

      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="style/images/sample1.jpeg">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="style/images/sample2.jpeg">two</a></li>
        <li><a id="first" href="style/images/Slideshow-Image1.jpg">one</a></li>

      <li class="background" style="visibility: hidden; zoom: 1; opacity: 0; left: 0px; top: 188px; width: 166px; height: 28px; "><div class="inner"></div></li></ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's `bear with me` I think in this context.

Comment: @Jared - Correct, unless she wants us to undress with her.

Comment: @Sara - You'll need to post some markup too.  Elements aren't simply in a Z-index free-for-all... how they're nested (parent->child relationships) affects how they position.  However, since #pictures & #menu appear to be siblings, I think you just need to set a z-index on those.  Since subscribe appears to be a child of pictures, it should be on top of the base object anyway.

Comment: @Sara - This is just my personal opinion, but the way you have your CSS formatted can be hard to read and debug. I don't know if this is how you typically do it, but I learned at one point that everything on one line is prone to errors. (CSS minimization notwithstanding.)

Comment: @Sara - Also note that there is a missing `;` in your CSS.

Comment: @John - I didn't feel it appropriate to point out the other option. :)

Comment: what about it is not working out?

Comment: Jared - thanks for your feedback. Not usually how I do my css, but, TBH, I don't usually css :). Need a bit more practice.

Comment: @Sara - In case you think I'm pulling your leg, this CSS file is the "teachable moment": https://web3.unt.edu/riskman/CSS/General.css That's about 6 1/2 years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're close. But to keep it simple, I would just put the z-index on slightly different elements (namely the main container elements).

Have a play with the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/irama/GwcsF/1/

The key bits being:

```
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow #pictures {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

#slideshow #menu {
    right: 0;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

#slideshow #pictures .subscribe {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Is that roughly what you were looking for? Let us know how you go!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `position: relative` for any parent DIV (with the image in it). Any layers to overlay that DIV must be nested inside the parent and with the CSS attribute set to `position: absolute`.

This sets the nested DIV tag to sit at the top left of it's parent, and overlay it. Then the z-index should work.

Hope that helps.

Ref: http://css-tricks.com/3118-text-blocks-over-image/

Answer (score 1):

Post the related HTML, please!

However, the *contents* of blocks appear to be getting the z-indices, but this will often not work because of the "Stacking contexts".  See [***Overlapping And ZIndex***](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex).

So, depending on the HTML, you'll probably need to set `z-index` on the  `#pictures` and `#menu` containers.